# Trying to understand the scope of the context in drawrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drawrect

I'm trying to understand how to keep values used by drawrect unique across instances of my class.
The example class below draws a triangle.
The way it is set up now if you create two instances of this using [[alloc] initWithFrame] where the two frames are of different sizes you will notice that both triangles are drawn at the size of the second instance of the class. If your first instance is small than the second it will be clipped by its rect.

1. If I declare tSize within drawrect the sizes will be different (correct)
2. If I declare tSize within ATriangle.h and @synthesize the sizes will be different (correct)
3. The two initWithFrame methods are run consecutively, then the two drawrects are run, presumably from the needsDisplay queue.

So my question is, exactly how does the scope work with regard to drawrect because none of the tutorials I read mention this behavior in anything but the vaguest of terms. They say that there is only one context, and that would seem so with these two instances but they don't appear to share that with my other classes. I missed the boat on this. What on earth is going on?

```
#import "ATriangle.h"

@implementation ATriangle
UIColor *divColor;

CGFloat tSize;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        divColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5];
        self.tSize = (frame.size.width / 3);

    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{


    CGContextRef context     = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, divColor.CGColor);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context,    (rect.size.width / 2), 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, (rect.size.width / 2)-tSize, tSize);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context,    (rect.size.width / 2) , 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, (rect.size.width / 2)+tSize, tSize);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, (rect.size.width / 2)-tSize, tSize);

    CGContextFillPath(context);
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `divColor` and `tSize`. You have declared them as file global variables, not instance variables. This means every instance of the class shares the same copy of the variables.

You want this:

```
@implementation ATriangle {
    UIColor *divColor;
    CGFloat tSize;
}
```

This will make the variables private instance variables instead of file globals.

Comment: Boy, I feel pretty bright right now. That's a habit I picked up from a tutorial somewhere. Terrible! I had no idea they were globals.